# Does mongo lock documents in bounds of UpdateOneAsync call?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, .net-core

I need to make a field of a document updatable only once with a specific value, even in a concurrent environment. For example, a document with an Id `123456` has a (string) field `SomeField` with initial value equal to `null`. I came up with a code that looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> SetSomeField(string id, string value)
{
    var updateResult = await GetCollection().UpdateOneAsync(
        x =>
            x.Id == id &&
            (!x.SomeField.HasValue || x.SomeField.Value == value),
        Builders<SomeDocument>
            .Update
            .Set("SomeField", value));

    return updateResult.MatchedCount != 0;
}
```

If two threads try to call this method, for example like `await SetSomeField("123456", "value1")` and `await SetSomeField("123456", "value2")` one call should set the value of `SomeField` and return `true` and the other one should return `false`. It is important that all subsequent calls continue to return the same value as they did for the first time.

In other words, I need to make this method idempotent in concurrent environment.

This code seems to be working fine, however I'm not sure if after condition is met, mongo locks a document in some way in order to make sure that it's not being updated concurrently.

Will that solution work, or do I need some external locking mechanisms?

Please comment if the question lacks any necessary details, I'll be happy to provide them.

Comment: mongo locks the whole collection when updating, you don't need any locks in your code. you can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use)

Comment: It may lock the collection while updating, but does this lock persist from the moment the condition is checked until the moment the update is over?

Comment: *"one call should set the value of SomeField and return true and the other one should return false."* - Why? If you actually look at the write result for any successive ( and they **will** happen successively ) update and one will show a "modified" count and the other will not. That's a little magic of `$set` and other like operators in that they don't actually "modify" anything that's actually in the state. Consider the `$inc` operator, which simply increments a value "in the state it was found". So I think you're looking to guard against something that does not really exist.

Comment: @NeilLunn what do you mean, why? Because it's required that this method should work as I described.

Comment: @NeilLunn `SetSomeField` should be idempotent in concurrent environment, that's the requirement, I clarified that in an edit.

Comment: Look at the `updateResult`. What I'm telling you is  that already tells you what happened. And two things **never** occur at the same time. If you send the same value, one modifies and subsequent requests with the same value do not. 1 millisecond or 1 eon later. Same value means not modified. That's what `.Set()` does.

Comment: @NeilLunn but that's the point though, the second set should not be run.

Comment: @nicks I'm not sure I follow. By definition, the async method will run asynchronously, so you can't really tell if they're run at the same time. Modern CPU also frequently reorder your calls. Unless you introduce a timing parameter e.g. `SetSomeField(<id>, <value>, <time>)`. However, it's highly unlikely two calls to this will run at **exactly** the same time down to the millisecond. Perhaps rather than describing your solution and asking about the problem with the solution, it's better to describe what your app is trying to achieve instead? There could be another way to do this.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha as I said, it's not important which one of the two calls will return `true` and which one will return `false`. What is important though, that after that, all subsequent calls should be the same, so 100% of the time, a call with same arguments should yield the same result. `SetSomeField` should be idempotent, as I said.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha sure, they may not happen at *exactly* the same time, however there might be an overlap while executing `UpdateOneAsync`, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @nicks so if I understand correctly, you want the async code to behave more like a single threaded process? What I still don't understand is that `SetSomeField()` will only return `True` or `False`. What do you mean by "subsequent calls with the same argument should yield the same result"? So a `SetSomeField(<id>, "value1") `once it returns `True` will always return `True`, and `SetSomeField(<id>, "value2")` once it returns `False` will subsequently always return `False`?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha yes, by the definition of idempotency.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic please note that the WiredTiger storage engine (default since MongoDB 3.2 released in Dec 2015) has document-level concurrency, and support many different features e.g. compression. See [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) for more details.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha what does compression have to do with the question?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use global to update to cloud data, or else when two threads try to call it, they won't interfere.

Comment: If you actually look at the write result for any successive ( and they will happen successively ) update and one will show a "modified" count and the other will not. That's a little magic of $set and other like operators in that they don't actually "modify" anything that's actually in the state. Consider the $inc operator, which simply increments a value "in the state it was found".